# Block quote in bookdown/rmarkdown footnotes

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I am writing in `thesisdown` (based on `bookdown`). One of my footnotes contains a rather long quote, and the `^[footnote text]` doesn't work, since,

if I use

```
hey^[as he says:
> some quotes
]
```

gives " as he says: > some quotes" in the foornote, and if I write like this:

```
hey^[

as he says:
> some quotes

]
```

or this:

```
hey^[
as he says:

> some quotes
]
```

it interprets it as normal text in the body, not footnote.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For footnotes with multiple paragraphs you should use the [regular footnote syntax](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#footnotes). In your case:

```
hey[^1]

[^1]: as he says:

    > some quotes

    regular text
```

Note the indentation of the following paragraphs with four spaces.